# Getting Run time error 9 and Compile error run

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am getting the value(string) of a cell from another sheet, by running it Under for loop. It is showing run-time error 9. It was showing compile error, so I removed set, and now it is showing run-time error 9. Please find the below code for reference:

```
For i = 2 To lastCol
    res_nam1 = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
    MsgBox res_nam1   
Next i
```

Comment: See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: check the spelling of ***sheet1***

Comment: Its working fine now. Was dealing with 2 sheets. Didn't activated the current sheet when I switched to current sheet from the other sheet.